# iphone: how to set UISegmentedCotrol at navigation item programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uisegmentedcontrol

I need to implement `UISegmentedControl` on navigation item pro grammatically because I `do not have XIB for that`.

Navigation item already have `title`,`left bar button`,and `right bar button`
Can I put it in between `left bar button` and `title`

Also how can I give event to that Control pro grammatically?

I have used the below code:

```
segImport = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Own",@"Imported",nil]];
                 [segImport setFrame:CGRectMake(80, 0, 200, 30)];
    [segImport setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
```

Comment: no you can not put a segment control between leftbar button and title .What you can do is either add your left bar button in segment control as one more segment and add that segment control in left bar button item.

Comment: @Gypsa: Is that really possible?

Comment: @Gypsa, you are right right i won't be able to put segmented control between leftbarbutton and title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Heena: Hi..

You just need to prepare the UISegmented Control as you normally do.

Then you need to use:

UIBarButtonItem *seg = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentControlObject];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = seg;

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

As far as you question whether you can place it between leftbarbutton and title. Then the answer is No, You cannot do it that way.

But if you want a way to make it work/work around for that, then please feel free to contact me.

Comment: you are right. I can't do it that way so I put it underneath of navigation bar

Answer (score 5):

There is not much room in a navigation bar, but you can add your segmented control to the navigation bar's title view like this:

```
 [[self navigationItem] setTitleView:segImport];
```

Check out this [article](http://redartisan.com/2010/5/26/uisegmented-control-view-switching) for a full tutorial on accomplishing this.

Comment: Other options would include putting the segmented control in either the toolbar at the bottom of the screen or underneath the navigation bar.

Comment: underneath the navigation bar can be one option but mine is UITableViewController class

Answer (score 1):

The following code may help you,

```
UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 40)];
UISegmentedControl *segment = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"One", @"Two", @"Three"]];
segment.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 40);
[segment addTarget:self action:@selector(onSegmentChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[customView addSubview:segment];
self.navigationItem.titleView = customView;

- (void)onSegmentChanged:(id)sender
{
    UISegmentedControl *segment = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;
    if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {

    }
    else if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {

    }
    else if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigation bars are a little tricky. I don't think you can add another item as a subview into it since you're reached the max of two, so you'll just have to position the UISegmentedControl over the navigation bar. As for detecting when the segmented control's selected segment changes, use this switch statement:

```
switch (self.segementControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {

    case 0: {

        //the first segment is selected
        break;

    } case 1: {

        //the second segment is selected
        break;

    } case 2: {

        //the third segment is selected
        break;

    } default: {

        break;

    }
```

Comment: I need to put this code in any of function right? then how control will know that now it should call this function?

Comment: When the value of the segmented control changes, then this code should be called.